# Link in popup doesn't works

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile to create a little mobile website.

I have a popup with a link, but this link works only if the popup is not taller than the phone screen. But it works on a computer...

The cross to close the popup is illuminated when I click on my link.

```
<div id="trouverUnMatch" data-role="page">

    <div id="notification" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="b">
        STUFF HERE
        <a href="#allNotifications">More</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="allNotifications" data-role="page">

</div>
```

**Edit**: It's not a problem with the bottom link, when I click on everywhere inside the popup it go to the popup top and illuminate the close button.

For example if you go to http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/ and click on a picture (Photo lightbox), you resize your browser to get only the half of it (in height), then if you click on the picture the close button will be illuminated.

Comment: Post your jQuery and CSS code snippet

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PTfNx833

Comment: apparently it works with Android but not with iOS (I don't know about Windows Phone)

Answer (score 0):

I have replace the link by :

```
<span class="link" data-link="allNotifications">More</span>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".link").on('tap', function () {

        $.mobile.changePage( "#" + $(this).attr("data-link") );

    });

});
```

It works with iOS but chrome on desktop has the problem now...